# Is this a valid proof for checking if a number K is dividable by 11,

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, divisibility

let s = $a_{0}+a_{1}+......+a_{n}$

let k = $a_{0}+a_{1}*10^{1}+......+a_{n}*10^{n}$

k-s = $a_{1}*(9_{1})+a_{2}*(9_{1}9_{2})+......+a_{n}*(9_{1}9_{2}....9_{n})$

It is obvious that 11 will divide any term in the sequence where the number of 9's is even. so we only have to worry about the odd terms

let k-s = t+r

where t contains terms with the even number 9's, which are all divisible by 11
and r contains the terms with odd numbers

r = $a_{1}*(9_{1})+a_{3}*(9_{1}9_{2}9_{3})+......a_{2n+1}*(9_{1}9_{2}....9_{2n+1})$

each term in r can be decomposed for all $(2n+1)>1$

$a_{2n+1}*(9_{1}9_{2}....9_{2n+1})= a_{2n+1}*(9*10^{2n}) + a_{2n+1}*(9_{1}....9_{2n})$

where $a_{2n+1}*(9_{1}....9_{2n})$ is divisible by 11

we know that $(9*10^{2n})$ is never divisible by 11. Therefore for r to be divisible by 11 all $a_{2n+1}$ must be divisible by 11.

Therefore for k-s to be divisible by 11 the sum of all the odd digits must equal to 11

k = (k-s) + s = t+r + s

using what we have already proved if k is divisible by 11 then t is divisible by 11, always, and the r is dividable by 11 if the sum of the odd terms of digits is 11

lastly the sum of the even terms must also be be divisible by 11 as s must be divisible by  11 for k to be divisible by 11

Therefore the sum of the odd and even terms in the digits must sum to a number divisible by 11 for K to be divisible by 11

**P.S here is the correct proof**

let k = $a_{0}+a_{1}*10^{1}+ a_{2}*10^2......+a_{n}*10^{n}$

CASE 1 ODD NUMBER OF DIGITS in K expansion:

k = $a_{0}+a_{1}*(1_{1}1_{2})-a_{1}+a_{2}*(9_{1}9_{2})+a_{2}......a_{n}*(1_{1}1_{2}....1_{n})-a_{n}$

k = $a_{1}*(1_{1}1_{2})+a_{2}*(9_{1}9_{2})+......+a_{n}*(1_{1}1_{2}....1_{n}) + (a_{0}-a_{1}+a_{2}-.......-a_{n})$

We can see that all the terms $a_{1}*(1_{1}1_{2})+a_{2}*(9_{1}9_{2})+......+a_{n}*(1_{1}1_{2}....1_{n})$ are divisible by 11

Therefore for k to be divisible by 11 the $(a_{0}-a_{1}+a_{2}-.......-a_{n})$ must divisible by 11 or equal zero. Which is the difference of the odd and even terms

CASE 2 : EVEN NUMBER OF DIGITS

WLOG we apply the same argument for an even number of digits. The only difference in the proof is that the last term in $(a_{0}-a_{1}+a_{2}-.......)$ will have a different sign. However the end result will mean the same. That the difference in odd and even digits determines whether a number is divisible by 11

Comment: There are two ways to formulate the divisibility-rule for $11$ $1)$ : A number is divisible by $11$ , if and only if the alternating digitsum is divisible by $11$ $2)$ : A number is divisible by $11$ if and only is the sum of the $2$-blocks in which we divide the number (where a single digit can remain) is divisible by $11$.

Comment: The first variant is based on $\ 10\equiv -1\mod 11\ $ , the second on $\ 100\equiv 1\mod 11\ $.

Comment: We can also say : The digits in the "even places" must have a sum with the same residue mod $11$ as the sum of the digits in the "odd places".

Comment: Damn,  This a huge ask, but do you know why or where I went wrong. Here I proved that the sum of the digits must equal a multiple of 11, which is wrong by what you are saying. I just can't see where the proof here breaks down.

Comment: or is what i proved equivalent to the other proofs? I know what I have proved is wrong because of 22 etc

Comment: For $9$, the digit-sum itself is sufficient, but this is obvious , since the summands of $k-s$ are all divisible by $9$. I think, the flaw has something to do with concluding that all summands are divisible by $11$ if no summand is divisible by $11$, if I understood the proof right. I can only say that the digit-sum itself cannot be used for the $11$-rule , which can also be easily seen by verifying some examples.

Comment: By the way, for $7$ it gets even more complicated !

Comment: I think I see the error. I’m in a car right now but I’ll upload the corrected version soon.

Comment: It stem from the error you pointed out that all summands have to be divisible by 11 for k-s. After that pint the entire proof is compromised

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110429/discussion-between-conrad-g-and-peter).